# What is the font used in Adobe software UI?

Tags: font-identification, adobe-premiere

I'm building my personal portfolio website, and just for fun I wanted to make the "Coming Soon" page look like an Adobe interface. I managed to get to a good-looking result but the only thing I am missing is the font used in Adobe software interface.

**For instance here in Premiere Pro CC 2017**

[image]

(this is the area with the most text I have found in Adobe software.)

First thought: "This must be Myriad Pro!" but obviously it isn't.

Google returned very few relevant results and no answer at all, WhatFontIs could not find it, same for WhatTheFont.

I'm sure someone here knows the answer!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @AasimAzam Windows 10, but I don't remember the font being different on Mac OS. Is it?

Comment: I have a feeling this is the standard system font. Segoe. I am not 100% sure though. But on my system its Segoe. This image is too small to get a proper gage. Look into changing the font in the system setting and see if it changes.

Comment: On Windows, it's a pretty close match for Segoe UI. Not sure about MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, it could be a couple of **default system fonts:**

### Windows

As per the comments on the OP, that font *could* render as **Segoe UI** on newer versions of Windows, but based on your image it's most likely Segoe's predecessor **Tahoma:**

[image]

---

### Mac OS

Similar to Windows, the most recent Mac OS *could* use **San Francisco**, but the interface on my own computer appears to use SF's predesccesor **Lucida Grande:**

[image]

---

***One last point:*** I can't speak for the Windows OS, but I'm running on the most up to date Mac OS and Adobe CC and it still uses Lucida Grande. My guess is neither operating system will use the newer proprietary system fonts mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

It's called 'Adobe Clean.' You probably couldn't find it online because it's not available for public use.

"*Adobe’s corporate typeface family was announced in 2009. It is not available for licensing*."
https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/32564/adobe-clean

You can, however, see that it is indeed this font by using the Inspect Element tool on the Creative Cloud section of the Adobe website:

[image: adobe website inspect element font family].

Comment: Another possibility is this: http://adobe-fonts.github.io/source-sans-pro/

Comment: Thank you for this answer! (I see you subscribed just to answer me, wow). I guess I'll have to find an alternative font.

Comment: Mh, doesn't look like Source Sans. Look at the j...

Comment: Well, just looked at Adobe Clean presentation slides and it doesn't look like it either. :/

Answer (score 0):

Source Sans Pro is very close and available [from Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro).